# typo3 using the link-wizard in custom be-module

Tags: typo3, extbase, fluid

I can't possibly be the only one with this problem…

I'm creating a be-module with fluid-forms for my be-module. I have image-fields in my model, which - when used in the list-module of the T3-Backend - provide me with the wizard to select files from the fileadmin-tree.

But I want to use this in my own module. Rather than just creating an `f:form.upload` field, I want users to be able to select files from fileadmin.
Much like in a provider-extension where `<flux:field.inline.fal name="myFALReference" required="1" maxItems="1" minItems="1"/>` creates a complete wizard to select files.

Using flux in my own be-module doesn't seem to work. When I use the above, nothing is rendered in my form.

I wrote my own wizard like two years ago ([Using the link wizard in a Typo3 backend module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219528/using-the-link-wizard-in-a-typo3-backend-module)), but this is cumbersome and not very elegant.

Heck, there's a wizard in the list module, flux does it, why isn't this available in fluid???

Or am I missing something completely and thinking way too much complicated?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: When using forms in backend, why not using the existing forms you can handle with TCA? Is that not possible to use them? Would be much easier.

Comment: Using T3-10 - and TCA apparently doesn't have any effect on handwritten be-modules.

Comment: Your approach from 2 years ago looks pretty good. That's how you would do it if you would want to use FormEngine directly. flux is not "doing" it by the way. flux dynamically configures Flexforms which are included in a table TCA. That's how you get FormEngine for free (You do not need FlexForm of course, just a renderType=inputLink). You can easily link to your record(s) with these Backend-Viewhelpers: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/master/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/ViewHelpers/Link - that will open the edit mask rendered by FormEngine.

Comment: @JonasEberle sadly, my approach with using FormEngine doesn't work in T3-11 anmyore. I tried to use InputLinkElement but the config seems to be wrong. The field wizard isn't initialized anymore. Any hints?